# Contenet of modal not showing in reactNative

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-paper

**Code Of Modal 1/2 **
[image: Modal code 1]

**part 2/2 **

[image: Modal Code 2]

***When i clicked to add User Popup Opne but text box not showing Thanx in advanced I am new to react-native***
**OutPut **
[image: Output Don't know why my textbox not showings]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your text inputs inside a View and give styling to that View(try to give flex 1 or height and width)

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  {... your text inputs here}
</View>
```

If {flex: 1} doesn't work, try giving static height and width {height: 200, width: 200}